# prevent page from refreshing after clicking a button

Tags: php, html

After a button is clicked, the page refreshes, which interferes with further functions of the page.
I tried changing the type from "submit" to "button", but then the button doesn't work at all. I also tried to return false the functions.

My simple code goes like this

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="Get" action=""> 
<input type="submit" name="buttonV" onclick="function1()"> <br>
<input type="submit" name="buttonS" onclick="funciton2()">
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php

 if ($_GET) {
        if (isset($_GET['buttonV'])) {
            function1();
        } elseif (isset($_GET['buttonS'])) {
            function2();
        }
    }
    
    function function1()
    { 
      // do stuff
    } 
    
    function function2()
    {
       // do stuff
    }

?>
```

What should I do in order to prevent the page to refresh?

Comment: `onclick="function1()"` calls a JavaScript function but your functions appear to be PHP

Comment: You are writing the code (functions) in PHP, so if page is not refreshed (more technically the page doesn't get a round trip to the sever which can run PHP...) then how come the PHP code will even run. You need to understand the difference between client side code which is mostly java script, and the server side code. If you dont want the page to refresh your functions should be in java script instead of PHP. Or you need to learn how to use ajax in php which can run your server side code without refreshing the whole page.

Comment: In your javaScript, do a preventDefault() on buttons inside your form.

Comment: Submit buttons SUBMIT

Answer (score -1):

I saw you are using php. I don't you use javascript.
You can use 'event.preventDefault()'.